# How to reverse the order of a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a table as listed below:

```
X   Y   Z
-----------
1   10  100
2   20  200
3   30  300
4   40  400
```

I would like to reverse only the order of column Y with out impacting the rest of the data.

 The output should look like:

```
X   Y   Z
-------------
1   40  100
2   30  200
3   20  300
4   10  400
```

Could anybody please help me with it?

Comment: Which DBMS? And what have you tried so far?

Comment: It can't be both sql-server and oracle. which one is it?

Comment: People are not here to do your homework, tell us what you have tried so far.

Comment: I am really sorry for the confusion. It was my first post and got confused with the tags. Its for SQL server.

Comment: Updated the tag to SQL server

Comment: @BigDataLearner have you checked answer

Comment: I am wondering what this is used for? What is the benefit of changing the records based on some arbitrary ordering? Don't forget, that the values of X-Y-Z columns is describing/quantifying something meaningful (business value?). The meaning of the first entry in your sample table has changed, because the Y value has changed (1-10-100 means something different than 1-40-100 and the latter is not what you have stored in the table). I am really curious what is this thing for.

Answer (score 1):

Check This.

```
            select b.X,a.Y,b.Z from
            (
            select X,   Y,Z, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Y DESC) as rnk1
            from #tableName 
            )a 
            inner join
            (
            select X,Y,Z,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Y)aa
            from #tableName t 
            )b
            on a.rnk1=b.aa
```

OR

```
            select X,50-Y ,Z from
            #tableName t1
```

> OutPut :

[image]

Comment: Thanks much Bhosale.

Comment: @BigDataLearner MW . If its work for you then mark as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a SQL Server solution for you:

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (x INT, y INT, z INT);
INSERT INTO @table SELECT 1, 10, 100;
INSERT INTO @table SELECT 2, 20, 200;
INSERT INTO @table SELECT 3, 30, 300;
INSERT INTO @table SELECT 4, 40, 400;
WITH Reversed AS (
    SELECT
        x,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY x) AS r1,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY x DESC) AS r2
    FROM
        @table)
SELECT
    t1.x,
    t2.y,
    t1.z
FROM
    Reversed r
    INNER JOIN @table t1 ON t1.x = r.r1
    INNER JOIN @table t2 ON t2.x = r.r2
ORDER BY
    t1.x;
```

Comment: Thanks much Richard. Using your query, I was able to get the desired answer.

Answer (score 0):

I used the query below:

```
--table name=xyz and the columns are X,Y,Z

WITH reverse_maker AS
 (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER
 (
  ORDER BY X DESC
  ) AS reverse_y
  FROM xyz  
  ORDER BY `xyz`.`X` ASC
 )

SELECT x, reverse_y*10 AS reversed_y, z 
FROM reverse_maker;
```

And you will get your desired result.